# How do I make my slideshow of Photos appear when the page opens, instead of when I click the dots, HTML CSS JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I am creating a slide show of photos using HTML CSS and JavaScript. The slideshow works but you can't see it when you open the webpage only the dots, when you click on the dots it then appears. It also disappears when the webpage refreshes. There are three pictures and it also seems that they are out of order (going 2,3,1 instead of 1,2,3).
Please how do I fix this?

This is my code.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  setTimeout(showSlides, 60000); // Change image every 60 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', sans-serif;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', sans-serif;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
      <!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div><div class="text">Testimonial One</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="Photos/T1.png" style="width:100%">
    
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div> <div class="text">Testimonial Two</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="Photos/T2.png" style="width:100%">
   
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div><div class="text">Testimonial Three</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="Photos/T3.png" style="width:100%">
    
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript (tags and code) is not the same as Java (title)

Answer (score 0):

For the button appearing in mixed up order, try

```
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(0)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

and

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
```